# A hotel owner finds that an average of 150 rooms are booked when the price is 175/night and 160 rooms are booked when the price is 160 per night.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

The question is to find the marginal revenue when 100 rooms are booked.

So far, I have the revenue function, $R(x)=-150x^2+400x$

I have the marginal function, $R'(x)= -300x +400$

I don't know how to move forward but from the answer sheet, the final answer is $250/night.

Comment: How did you come up with the revenue function?
Also what have you tried/what are your thoughts?

Comment: $p(x)=175-15n$ $x=150+10n$ I substituted the x into p(x) which gave me $-150x+400$ I multiplied that with x to find the revenue function. If there is another way or if the function is wrong, please let me know.

Comment: The hotel owner should use price discrimination in order to maximize profits.

Answer (score 0):

$p(150)=175$ and $p(160)=160$. Assuming a linear price function, we have $p(x) = 400-1.5 x$. Then $R(x)=xp(x)=-1.5 x^2 + 400 x$ with $R'(x)=-3x+400$ so the marginal revenue at 100 rooms is $R'(100)=100$.

The given answer of $250$ seems to be the price $p(100)=250$ when 100 rooms are booked. Perhaps you were looking at the answer for a different part of this question?